# Windows Authentication not triggering on site when first loaded

Tags: google-chrome, windows-authentication

I have a website that uses WDA to authenticate our users.  On Firefox and Chrome it works as expected, when the user logs in to our portal, they are stopped with a popup to insert their credentials.  However, on Chrome, this prompt is not immediate, and it takes them to our page with blank data with our message that no user is logged in.  It is only when I reload the page will the prompt appear, and the user can continue on normally.  I cannot figure out where this issue may appear, and googling doesn't appear to have helpful results for me.  Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: A network trace from f12 / fiddler / wireshark might help to solve your problem

Comment: Will try now, thanks!